# NTFS Extended Attributes,

Tags: windows, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I have been struggling to understand how exactly NTFS Extended file Attributes works.
I'm studying the Data Loss Prevention(DLP) products (like Symantec, McAfee, Forcepoint DLP products). and in the DLP products, there has a mechanism that the DLP can insert a **Classification ID** into the file to **classify the file** so that even the file is sent out to another PC, the DLP still can track the file if the target PC installs DLP software as well.
I want to know-**how is the Classification ID embedded into the file**,
googled this a lot but still unsure of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is the wrong place for this question. The question is not about C++ code. I don't know which is the right place, but there are numerous other stackexchange sites

Comment: "Even the file is sent out to another PC" -- I presume this refers to calling `CopyFileExW` to copy the file to a remote path using a filesystem redirector that supports setting extended attributes on the remote target file, such as SMB. Often copying or transmitting a file by other means just copies the file's default data stream and maybe basic metadata such as simple file attributes (flags) and the last-write and change timestamps. Alternate data streams and extended metadata such as extended file attributes and security resource attributes usually are not copied.

Comment: @ErykSun I have tried Alternate Data Streams(ADS) and yes it lost when sent to another pc over the internet.

Comment: My curiosity is rising that how DLP software classifies the files.

Comment: If it's using extended file attributes, then just query them to see what's there via [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile): `FileEaInformation` (for the required buffer size) and [`NtQueryEaFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-zwqueryeafile).

Comment: ok I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Data classification softwares do not use extended attribute for classification. Alternate data streams are used for some file formats. For MS Office files *OpenXml* and *DsoFile* can be used based on the file version. Here the classification ID is part of the data stream itself.